# How to print/log the CPU performance data from TRACE32?

Tags: debugging, embedded, trace, trace32, lauterbach

I'm able to view the CPU performance data/graph in GUI. But I would like to have it logged/printed in a file. There are few ways to save the traces in the file formats `.ad` & `.perf` (which are not human readable. They need to be reloaded into TRACE32  to get a proper understanding). Is there a way to write/print them into a human readable format? like `.txt` (Thanks in Advance)

Comment: I'm happy to provide more details if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In the GUI

Left click on the top left corner of a Window. In the pull down menu you'll find the options

- Print
- Print all
- To Clipboard
- To Clipboard all
- Window Screenshot to File...
- Window Screenshot to Clipboard

## In a script (using commands)

You can print the contents of a window using

`WinPrint.<command>`

for example

`WinPrint.Data.dump 0--0xfff`

or

`WinPrint.Analyzer.List (-1000.)--100. Address Data sYmbol`

To print to a file you must use

`PRinTer.FILE [<file>] [<format>] [/Append]`

beforehand, for example,

`PRinTer.FILE example.txt ASCIIE`

You can find the documentation here: https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/ide_ref.pdf

Comment: Bunch of thanks & I ended up exploring the same... But I've another question regarding the interpretation of ```.ad``` files which I should post it a separate question I guess